# convert a wchar_t array to PUNICODE_STRING

Tags: c++, c, windows, string

I have a const string - "testfilename.sys", and I want to create a `PUNICODE_STRING` that will hold it.
How can I do that?

Comment: Websearch suggests that RtlInitUnicodeString is the answer

Comment: PUNICODE_STRING is just Microsoft's (unwise, in my opinion) habit of `typedef`ing pointers, the data type is called `UNICODE_STRING`.

Answer (score 2):

As @David Heffernan pointed out, [RtlInitUnicodeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648420%28v=vs.85%29) is the way to create UNICODE_STRING structures.

In your case:

```
#include <Winternl.h>

[...]

UNICODE_STRING myUnicodeStr;
RtlInitUnicodeString(&myUnicodeStr, L"testfilename.sys");
```

A `PUNICODE_STRING` is just `UNICODE_STRING*`.

Answer (score 0):

there's RTL_CONSTANT_STRING macro in wdk which can be used to create UNICODE_STRING in compile time.